# How to restore focus to quick panel after focusing some other group to open a file?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Situation is like this: I am writing a plugin that needs to:

1. Open quick panel
2. On hover of first item, focus other group
3. Open in that group
4. Restore focus to quick panel input so I can move to next item in list and so on...

I did solve 1-3 but the 4th one gives me troubles. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to get the *view* associated with the *quick panel***. The method *show_quick_panel* doesn't returns the *view*, but you can get it with using the method *on_activated* with a *EventListener* plugin.

This method (*on_activated*) is called when you focus any view (tab, console, quick_panel...). So what this plugin will do is capture the view associated with the *quick panel*.

Example plugin to get the *view*:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class Example(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_activated(self, view):
        """This method is called whenever a view (tab, quick panel, etc.) gains focus, but we only want to get the quick panel view, so we use a flag"""
        if hasattr(sublime, 'capturingQuickPanelView') and sublime.capturingQuickPanelView == True:
            sublime.capturingQuickPanelView = False
            """View saved as an attribute of the global variable sublime so it can be accesed from your plugin or anywhere"""
            sublime.quickPanelView = view
            print(sublime.quickPanelView)
```

Now in your plugin you need to tell the *eventListener* when the actived view corresponds to the quick panel in order to capture it. Example of what you need in your plugin:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class Sample(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def restoreQuickPanelFocus(self):
        """Restore focus to quick panel is as easy as focus in the quick panel view, that the eventListener has previously captured and saved"""
        self.window.focus_view(sublime.quickPanelView)

    def on_highlighted(self, index):
        """Open image[index] in group 1"""
        self.window.focus_group(1)
        self.window.open_file(self.items[index])
        """Wait for image to open and restore focus to quick panel"""
        sublime.set_timeout(self.restoreQuickPanelFocus, 100)

    def run(self):
        print('runando')
        """Divide layout (as an example) """
        self.window.set_layout({
            "cols": [0.0, 0.4, 1.0],
            "rows": [0.0, 0.6, 1.0],
            "cells": [[0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2]]
            })

        """Items=> images paths"""
        self.items = ('C:/images/img1.jpg','C:/images/img2.jpg','C:/images/img3.jpg','C:/images/img4.jpg','C:/images/img5.jpg')

        """Now we are going to show the quick panel, so we set the capturing flag to true as the next activated view will correspond to quick panel"""
        sublime.capturingQuickPanelView = True
        self.window.show_quick_panel(self.items, None, sublime.KEEP_OPEN_ON_FOCUS_LOST , 0, self.on_highlighted)
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

The sergioFC's answer did not worked for me (sublime 3 3210) - the file view gains focus instead of the quick panel.

Some alternative https://sublimetext.userecho.com/communities/1/topics/2482-open-file-in-current-group-from-api
as a way to keep quick panel focused (files open in the current group)

```
self.window.open_file(items[index][2], 8|sublime.TRANSIENT)
```